# Importing .csv into Google Calendar

Tags: csv, google-calendar

I have been trying to import a .csv file into Google calendar and made sure to format it correctly and the file is well under the 1 MB limit. The first time I tried to import, it was successful, however when I tried to import another file using the same template, it gave me this error:

```
Failed to import events: Processing error during upload.
```

No matter what I do it does not seem to work. Any suggestions on how to fix this?